# Jenkins dashboard for multiple pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using jenkins with the pipeline plugin to build my microservices based application. This works basically, but there is no way to get a good overview which services have been build last for which branch and what the result was. Even the new Blue UI falls short :-(

I just want to have the name + last builds results for the pipelines to be able to see if something is going wrong somewhere.

I have searched for plugins which might help here but I had no luck.

**Has someone solved this in some way already?**

I don't want to spend my time writing my own visualization, but I am beginning to realize that this will be the way to go. :-/

**If nothing like this exists does someone know a good source to start to use the jenkins api for this kind of visualization?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View
It allows you to add a job list and specify the jobs to be included using a regular expression. Hence, new jobs for feature branches should appear automatically.

Comment: But can it filter projects? For example, I have 4 multibranch projects, and I only want to see jobs from a single one. I couldn't create a reject to match the project name

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this will be a one end to end product for you. I have been using it from the last 6 Months.
This is much better than the other Dashboards.

[Hygieia Dashboard](https://github.com/capitalone/Hygieia)

Comment: I have checked the product video, it looks like this is still focused on single pipelines and not on a big set of pipelines

Comment: hygieia project was archived on 1st June 2023.